# Best way to run Sonarqube local analysis with javascript project

Tags: javascript, maven, sonarqube

In our CI environment the SonarQube build breaker plugin is installed, and build will fail if Sonar scan alert threshold is reached. Developer needs to run SonarQube local analysis and fix any new issues and submit changes again.

But this process does not work for javascript project. SonarQube Eclipse plugin does not support javascript yet, while maven sonar runner only generates a json file as the result. This is not user friendly to developer.

So my question is: is there any other option to make javascript local analysis visualized besides installing local SonarQube server? Thanks.

Best Regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For developers to check their code prior to commit, they can use the Issues Report plugin for now. See http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Issues+Report+Plugin.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the SonarLint tool with Eclipse.

> SonarLint is an extension to your favorite IDE that provides on-the-fly feedback to developers on new bugs and quality issues injected into their code.

http://www.sonarlint.org